# How to run query conditionally in a plpgsql procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Some of my data models have relations which must be kept updated upon changes to their children, such as a multipoint location that is a collection of many children with point locations that have to be updated if a child is relocated. There are multiple of such relations, and I would like to handle maintaining the integrity of these relations in a single trigger+procedure that triggers the following procedure upon updating the relevant fields on the parent's affected relations.

How do I format these queries and conditionals such that it accomplishes the following:

```
CREATE TABLE parents (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    caption TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    tags CHARACTER VARYING(32)[] DEFAULT '{}',
    rating SMALLINT DEFAULT 0
)
CREATE TABLE children (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    tags CHARACTER VARYING(32)[] DEFAULT '{}',
    rating SMALLINT DEFAULT 0
)
CREATE TABLE parent_children (
    parent_id BIGINT,
    child_id BIGINT
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION child_updated_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF (OLD.tags != NEW.tags) 
            UPDATE parents
            SET tags = tags || NEW.tags
            WHERE
                parent_children.child_id =  NEW.id
                AND parents.id = parent_children.parent_id;
        IF (OLD.rating != NEW.rating) 
            UPDATE parents
            SET rating = MAX(parent_children.rating)
            FROM parent_children
            WHERE
                parent_children.child_id = NEW.id
                AND parents.id = parent_children.parent_id;
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER child_updated
    AFTER UPDATE ON children
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE child_updated_func();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF (OLD.tags != NEW.tags) THEN
            UPDATE parents
            SET tags = tags || NEW.tags
            WHERE
                parent_children.child_id =  NEW.id
                AND parents.id = parent_children.parent_id;
        END IF;
        IF (OLD.rating != NEW.rating) 
            UPDATE parents
            SET rating = MAX(parent_children.rating)
            FROM parent_children
            WHERE
                parent_children.child_id = NEW.id
                AND parents.id = parent_children.parent_id;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you!  And those queries are executed sequentially, correct?

Comment: @terpak Yes they are.

Comment: also just a heads up in case you want to update your answer, I removed the pseudocode in favor of having all of the sql information there, as per a_horse_with_no_name's request.  Thanks again!